# What's the concise expression for the following Matlab code

Tags: matlab

img is an image of a single color channel.
img_temp is defined as follows:

```
img_temp = zeros(size(img,1), size(img,2), N);
```

where N is an integer. Therefore, each entry of img_temp contains N values.

What's the concise way of expressing the following operation in Matlab?

```
for x=1:size(img,1)
    for y=1:size(img,2)
        img(x,y,1) = find(img_temp(x,y,:)==max(img_temp(x,y,:)));
    end
end
```

I want to find the index of the largest value in the array img_temp(x,y,:) and store it in the corresponding place in img, namely, img(x,y,1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [max](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) function can operate along any dimension and return an index along with the max value. In your case, you only care about the index and want it stored in `img(:,:,1)`, so try this:

```
[~, img(:,:,1)] = max(img_temp, [], 3);
```

Comment: @shapeare If this answer solves your problem you should consider "accepting" it by clicking the checkmark to the left. This not only lets other people know that this question has been resolved, it also gives the person whose answer is accepted additional reputation points.